# Exchangelib: Moving Email from Inbox to Folder

Tags: python, exchangelib

I want to read out the newest E-Mail in the inbox, select the attachment out of it and move the E-Mail to a folder. I already have a code to save the attachment:

```
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account
import os

credentials = Credentials('test.name@mail.com', 'password')
account = Account('test.name@mail.com', credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)
for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:1]:
    for attachment in item.attachments:
        fpath = os.path.join("C:/destination/path", attachment.name)
        with open(fpath, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(attachment.content)
```

But I have a problem to move the E-Mail to another folder than the inbox.
So far I only found this option:

```
item.move(to_folder)
```

But I don`t know how I should write in the name of the folder.
Could anyone give me an example for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

The `to_folder` argument to `.move()` must be a `Folder` instance, not a folder name. Here's an example:

```
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account
import os


credentials = Credentials('test.name@mail.com', 'password')
account = Account('test.name@mail.com', credentials=credentials, 
autodiscover=True)

#this will show you the account folder tree
print(account.root.tree())

#if to_folder is a sub folder of inbox
to_folder = account.inbox / 'sub_folder_name'

 #if folder is outside of inbox
 to_folder = account.root / 'folder_name'

for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:1]:
    for attachment in item.attachments:
        fpath = os.path.join("C:/destination/path", attachment.name)
        with open(fpath, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(attachment.content)
    item.move(to_folder)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, but now I get a CASError with "UnauthenticatedRequest", when I´m using the new code or even with the exact same code that worked on friday. Do you know, how to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

for me what worked was

```
account.inbox / 'foldername'
```

root would not work at all so I created a new folder under inbox